# how to prevent that <space> key is used inside insert-mode mappings?

Tags: neovim, insert-mode

in insert mode, when i press <kbd>space</kbd>, my neovim doesn't print out the space immediately. instead, it prints in the right corner `<20>` and seems to wait for a mapping to complete. Although my mapleader is <kbd>space</kbd>, i have no mappings using `<leader>` for insert mode.

(*update below*)

`:verbose imap <space>` prints out that some plugins define  mappings. Disabling those temporarily results in the correct behavior when pressing .

**My updated question is therefore: how can i prevent those insert-mode mapping of  ?**

That means, i want to know how i can forbid the use of (which is btw. my `<Leader>`) in *every* insert-mode mapping.

---

[image: pic]

```
$ nvim -v
NVIM v0.2.0-655-g0ef2b07d6
Build type: RelWithDebInfo
Compilation: /usr/bin/cc -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -Wconversion -O2 -g -DDISABLE_LOG -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wno-unused-parameter -Wstrict-prototypes -std=gnu99 -Wvla -fstack-protector-strong -fdiagnostics-color=auto -DINCLUDE_GENERATED_DECLARATIONS -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/tmp/yaourt-tmp-toogley/aur-neovim-git/src/neovim-git/build/config -I/tmp/yaourt-tmp-toogley/aur-neovim-git/src/neovim-git/src -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/tmp/yaourt-tmp-toogley/aur-neovim-git/src/neovim-git/build/src/nvim/auto -I/tmp/yaourt-tmp-toogley/aur-neovim-git/src/neovim-git/build/include
Compiled by toogley@arch-laptop

Optional features included (+) or not (-): +acl   +iconv    +jemalloc +tui      
For differences from Vim, see :help vim-differences

   system vimrc file: "$VIM/sysinit.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/nvim"
```

Comment: Did you confirm this by running `:verbose imap <space>` ?

Comment: @TommyA thanks a lot for that hint, didn't know that. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the plugin has some `<plug>mapping` variation point that could be used to override the default one thar use `<leader>`, well there will be a solution.

Otherwise, it's done on a per plugin basis.

Unless listing all i-mappings starting with `<space>` thanks to `getcompletions()` (IIRC) in an `after/` plugin executed after all other plugins, I don't see any generic solution -- note that this won't solve ftplugins issues.

PS: there exist many forks of a.vim that have disabled the mappings that cause the disturbances in your case. (I even have a [fork](https://github.com/LucHermitte/alternate-lite), for other reasons)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `:nnoremap` or `:nmap`

> causing the mapping to exist only in normal mode

Instead of just `:map` or `:noremap`

> Which causes the mapping to exist in all modes (I think)